# Custom subject line for email

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I am using a simple php mail form for an RSVP form for my wedding website, I am trying to put a custom subject on the email so when it shows up in my inbox it is easily recognizable.

Here is the code I am using

```
<?php

$myemail = "myemail@gmail.com";


$name = check_input($_POST['name']);
$howmany = check_input($_POST['howmany']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message']);


$message = "
Name: $name
How many people are coming with you?: $howmany

Anything Else?:
$message

";


mail($myemail, $howmany, $message);

header('Location: thanks.php');
exit();


function check_input($data='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
{

return $data;
}

?>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

This code works well, except when it shows up in my inbox the subject line is displaying $howmany for some reason

It would be ideal if the subject line displayed like this: **Wedding RSVP $name $howmany** (Displayed subject in my email box: Wedding RSVP Andrew Harris +4

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance to anybody who helps!

Comment: Look at the manual page for `mail`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - the second parameter you pass in is the subject line to use. So you just need to pass in the right string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the subject line is displaying $howmany for some reason

For this reason:

```
mail($myemail, $howmany, $message);
```

The second argument to [the `mail()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is the subject line.  If you want it to be a specific string, use that string:

```
mail($myemail, "Wedding RSVP $name $howmany", $message);
```